# suppress fatal error messages using wix

Tags: windows, wix, fatal-error, repair

I have an MSI, which checks a certain condition during repair, and if 
that condition fails,it gives a custom error and repair does not happen. 
However, when I do the repair from Add Remove programs, I see that i get my custom UI message for repair failure and then on clicking "OK", I am shown another dialog, saying "Fatal Error 
during installation." 
Is there any way to supress this fatal error message using WiX Installer.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: maybe is a thing about permissions, have you executed it in Admin mode?

Comment: yes executing it in Admin mode. Actually it is valid that my repairing will fail since i'm failing certain conditions but i want to supress that fatal error message from "Add/remove Programs" dialog.